# Matlab neural network is not learning

Tags: matlab, neural-network

Can someone please tell me if my code is wrong while trying to train my network for pattern recognition? I am desperate, for trying everything, since changing the Hn, epochs, normalized my data, etc... But the network does not seems to develop.

Here is the code

```
net = newff(p,t,15,{},'traingd');
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;  % Adjust as desired
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;  % Adjust as desired
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;  % Adjust as desired
net.trainParam.epochs = 10000;
net.trainParam.goal = 0.01;
net.trainParam.show = 25;
net.trainParam.time = inf;
net.trainParam.min_grad = 1e-10;
net.trainParam.max_fail = 10;
net.trainParam.sigma = 5.0e-5;
net.trainParam.lambda = 5.0e-7;
net.trainParam.mu_max = 1e-20;
net.trainParam.lr = 0.001; 

% Train and Apply Network
[net,tr] = train(net,p,t);
outputs = sim(net,p);

% Create P.

% Plot
plotperf(tr)
plotfit(net,p,t)
plotregression(t,outpts)
```

And I run it exactly like this. `p` and `t` are my inputs and targets respectivly. 
Is it only me, that when trying to run the toolbox (nprtool) is not able to introduce the target, unless it comes from the demos?

Answer (score 2):

When you start the GUI (nprtool), you should be able to choose the targets (and the inputs) from the variables in the workspace:

[image: nprtool]

Regarding your first question:

- Can you try learning synthetic data (which fits the model of course)?
- Can you try using the default `trainlm` option instead of `traingd`?

Comment: Thank you for anwsering. I do use the the variables from the workspace. What occurs is that When I open the target, it does not gives me the change to choose????? Can I ask something else? Twice I was able to train the network, and as soon as I change the targets, it continue not to train. I'm thinking it could be due to the weights, that I was lucky that in a week it could work twice. Do you know what are the best weights to start with? Thank you so much

Comment: It might be caused by problematic data, if the data is not following the neural-net model, then the algorithm might not converge.

Comment: But I do not understand why it converged twice, out of the many times I was trying. Trainlm normaly gives me a worse mse. I begining to be desperate, is it always like this? I thought of trying weka, but have a space problem and XMx is not solving it :(

Comment: Don't get desperate, it is a good tool as long as you use it correctly (like any other tool...). Usually the initial conditions are chosen randomly, so it might converge some of the times and not converge in other times.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to answer, it is great for one doing this kind of thing to have some feedback. I will keep on trying with the nntool trying to get a good weight and reading manuals..